# 403 forbidden resource error

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I am seeing this error after I merged some changes from some one else's code. I was able to browse to the directory fine before.

Now, Basically my localserver is throwing this error. and that is all it is saying. I did try running the project as admin and I tried giving iis full permission the folder and everything but no luck yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to read this https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the page on the web server - it may then give you the actual 403 error - e.g. 403.11 - then you can look up that error [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your comment and trusting the fact that I was not able to post much details because i did not have much details my self. <br/> To give  you some details, the merge that I did had added some web.config code which was doing some URL Rewrite stuff and also I noticed that my Apppool was changed for default website. Your comment was very helpful ONLY IE was showing detailed error code and it was 403.18. that gave me a clue that App pool was wrong. Now it is OK

Answer (score 0):

If you are not talking about a huge amount of merged changes applied to your repository, most probably, you will loose less time by

- undoing merge
- and checking one-by-one changes available on the server.

From my experience this often is a easiest way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I tried reverting my changes and it works fine. But at the same time it was important for me to figure out what broke it. As I said in the comment above, it was my apppool setting.

Comment: @Californicated: ok, what I mean, usually reverting and after checking the changes one-by-one usually saves time..